# Xperia z1 compact Android Lollipop Unable to read from '/sys/class/leds/wled:backlight/max_current'

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, sony, sony-xperia

After android 5 lollipop update I have a lot of error message on adb logcat console:

```
280-300/? E/leds-amami﹕ Unable to read from '/sys/class/leds/wled:backlight/max_current'
```

from ps

```
system    280   1     14284  1044  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/illumination_service
```

It is hard to develop on android  with this message every 50ms
Is there a solution or we must hope in an update?

Comment: Try this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=60362106&postcount=29 (require rooted z1c).

Comment: thanks,but I do not want to unlock my xperia and lose warranty I am writing here as suggested on sony mobile developer : http://developer.sonymobile.com/about/how-do-i-get-in-contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting for Sony answer I have found a workaround to exclude from logcat the booring message. I have realized a regex filter on Android Studio as in the image

[image: z1 leds-amami error]

Comment: the issue is solved in the Sony Android release 5.0.2 build 14.5.A.0.270